# Reading inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, mysqli

Please consider below Code.
I want to read emails on holder array ,
but when I try to access $holder['email'] , it fails.
 I want to check new entered email with old emails in data base.
here is the code :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" ,"note_db");
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//echo "Connected successfully";

$email = $_REQUEST ['email'];
$pass = $_REQUEST ['pass'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM users");

$holder = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$record = array();

$record ['email'] = $row['email'];
$holder [] =  $record;

}

if($holder['email'] == $email){
    echo "email was set before";
    return;
}
else{
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$email', '$pass')") ;
    echo "email Inserted to DataBase";

}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: `$holder[0]['email'];`

Comment: @aldrin27 its only returns the last email in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" ,"note_db");
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//echo "Connected successfully";

$email = $_POST ['email'];
$pass = $_POST ['pass'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM users");

$holder = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$holder [] =  $row;
}
foreach($holder as $val){
    if($val['email']==$email){
        echo "email was set before";
        return FALSE;
    }
    else{
         $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$email', '$pass')") ;
         echo "email Inserted to DataBase";
    }
}


mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" ,"note_db");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//echo "Connected successfully";

$email = $_REQUEST ['email'];
$pass = $_REQUEST ['pass'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM users");

$holder = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $record = array();

    $record ['email'] = $row['email'];
    $holder [] =  $record;

}

foreach( $holder as $key => $hold){
     if($hold['email'] == $email){
        echo "email was set before";
        return;
     }else{
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$email',  '$pass')") ;
        echo "email Inserted to DataBase";

     }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: thanks for your relpy.but when I use it , it returns this error 7 times (I have 7 rows) :  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in line 33 ,  Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in line 33 and ...

Comment: Thanks.But if we don't use $key , we get same result.its not necessary I think.

Answer (score 0):

That's beceause $holder['email'] doesn't exist.
$foo[] = "bar"  // Give you this array  "Array ( [0] => "bar )"
To get all emails in $foo you should loop on it

Edit : like how suggested @Shahid Ahmad

`foreach($holder as $h) { 
   echo $h['email']; 
}`

Comment: Thanks , but how can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to check if email is already taken then you can achieve the same result using a boolean flag. Also, consider using PDO or prepared statements. Furthermore, explicit set if you will take values from $_POST or $_GET.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" ,"note_db");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//echo "Connected successfully";

$email = $_POST['email']; //Or $_GET
$pass = $_POST['pass'];  //Or $_GET
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM users");

$found = false; //Boolean to check if email is already taken

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['email'] == $email) { //If email exists in database
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($found) { //If email exists in database
    echo "email was set before";
    return;
} else { //Email doesn't exist so inset, Consider using prepared statements
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$email', '$pass')") ;
    echo "email Inserted to DataBase";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Thanks Dear.It does work for finding used emails.but actually I want to know , how I can Read Inside the $holder Array.